# How to set multiple "Set-Cookie" headers on single response

Tags: node.js, http, go

How do I set multiple `Set-Cookie` headers like google does. Tried doing it in Go and Node.js but it doesn't seem possible.
Is it possible to do this without any framework(s)?

[image]

- Go

```golang
res.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", "q=city,c=acc; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax")
```

- Node.js

```js
 res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html",
    "Set-Cookie": "q=city,c=acc; HttpOnly; SamSite=Lax", 
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=120"
  });
```

Comment: *"Tried doing it in Go and Node.js but it doesn't seem possible."* - It would be helpful if you actually documented what exactly you've tried. Duplicate of [How do I set multiple http header fields with the same key in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397983/how-do-i-set-multiple-http-header-fields-with-the-same-key-in-node-js)

Comment: I want to know if it's supported by the core http module in both Go/Node.js

Comment: @theBashShell Yes, its supported. use `setHeader` and use a array for "set-cookie"/Cookie: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setheader_name_value

Comment: thanks @Marc I can confirm that works in Node.js

Answer (score 1):

For golang, `http.Header` has a [`Add` Method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Add), which would append instead of overwrite existing keys.

> Add adds the key, value pair to the header. It appends to any existing values associated with key. The key is case insensitive; it is canonicalized by CanonicalHeaderKey.

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js, use `setHeader` on the response with an array as value

```js
  res.writeHead(200, { 
    "Set-Cookie": ["q=city;HttpOnly", "lat=45; SameSite=Lax", "another=foo;SameSite=Lax;"] 
  });
```

For Go, use `Header().Add()` on the response

```golang
res.Header().Add("Set-Cookie", "q=city; SameSite=Lax")
res.Header().Add("Set-Cookie", "multiple=1; HttpOnly")
```